# The Hunter: Won't Launch

Tags: technical-issues, the-hunter

I have Windows 8 Operating system. First of all, I have already downloaded the game from Steam but it kept crashing at Launch so my friend recommended to redownload it from the Hunter website. And so I did. But now it starts to launch and then it closes with no error message or anything.

Rest of my PC:

- Windows 8.1 64bit
- Dual Core 3.5 GHz processor
- 258 MB of Video memory (yes really)
- 4 GB DDR2

Comment: Do you have the steam version of it installed? If so could you verify the cache of it? Also does your PC match the minimum requirements?                                                         `OS: Windows ® 8/7/Vista/XP 
Processor: Intel 2 GHz or AMD Dual Core 
Memory: 2 GB RAM 
Graphics: NVidia GeForce 8800, ATI/AMD Radeon HD 2400 (NVidia GeForce 8800, ATI/AMD Radeon HD 2400) 
DirectX: Version 9.0c 
Network: Broadband Internet connection 
Hard Drive: 7 GB available space 
Sound Card: DirectX Compatible`

Comment: "I have allready downloaded the game from Steam but it kept crashing at Launch so my friend recommended to redownload it compleatly from the Hunter website"

Comment: I understood that, but just wondering does you PC match the minimum specs?

Comment: Yes, i have checked and it dose!